# NameError undefined local variable or method `primary_abstract_class' for #<Class:xxxxx>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jruby, activemodel

I'm trying to run rails with jruby
`rails` : `6.1.4.4` | `jruby` : `9.3.3.0` | `ruby`  : `2.6.8`

I get this error for when i try to use any Model(s)
In rails console

```rb
User.all.limit(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from (irb):2:in `evaluate'
        3: from app/models/user.rb:1:in `<main>'
        2: from app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from app/models/application_record.rb:2:in `<class:ApplicationRecord>'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `primary_abstract_class' for #<Class:0x558123>)
Did you mean?  primary_class?
```

I have a User Model
`app/models/user.rb`

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

`app/models/application.rb`

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class
end
```

Comment: Looks like `primary_abstract_class` was added in rails 7.0. https://github.com/rails/rails/releases Did you add that yourself, if so, or really either way, remove it and everything should work appropriately.

Comment: I had to switch rails from `7.0` to `6.1.4.4` to run it on jruby, because the latest jruby `9.3.3.0` requires ruby `<2.7` and rails `7.0` requires atleast ruby `2.7`.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned `primary_abstract_class` is introduced in Rails 7.

In Rails < 7 the ApplicationRecord is generated with:

```rb
# app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```